# Get javascript variable value in label

Tags: c#, javascript, c#-4.0

I'm not able to get the JavaScript variable value in label. I'm trying in Windows application. Not able to use hidden field to get the value of variable. I tried below code but value is not coming in label.

```
document.getElementsByTagName('label3').Text=checkedIDs;//In java script
string val = label3.Text.Tostring();//This is how i'm trying to get label3 value.
```

I tried all the answers , but i'm not getting any value in label3.

```
HtmlElement head = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("head")[0];
        HtmlElement scriptEl = webBrowser1.Document.CreateElement("script");
        IHTMLScriptElement element = (IHTMLScriptElement)scriptEl.DomElement;
        element.text = " function sayHello(){var indices = [0,1];var checkedIDs = getCheckedResumeIDs(indices);if(checkedIDs.length == 0){alert('Please select at least one.');return false;}document.getElementById(\"<%=label3.ClientId%>\").value = checkedIDs;}";
        head.AppendChild(scriptEl);
webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("sayHello");
```

I'm injecting JavaScript into web page and trying to get result of a function.

Comment: In javascript you set the text of a label with `node.innerHTML += value`

Comment: Please show us the generated HTML (what the browser sees).

Comment: You seem to be trying to mix JS and C# in the same line, which doesn't help. `.getElementsByTagName()` returns a list of matching elements that you access like an array, but do you actually have an element with tagname "label3"? (As in `<label3>content</label3>`.)

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right, you need to change first line

```
document.getElementById("<%=label3.ClientId%>").value=checkedIDs;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing both `c#` and `javascript` functionality in the same line that is the wrong thing.

You are using `getElementsByTagName` which require the Name assinged to that `Label`.

If `label3` is a `Label` in c# then the code should be like this:

```
document.getElementsById('<%= label3.ClientID %>').value = checkedIDs;
```

Now you will get the value in the `label3` which you can access though c# code like you have done.

Answer (score 0):

Its wrong, you are using the wrong

Change `document.getElementsById`

with

```
document.getElementById
```

its Element and not Elements

So like this

```
document.getElementById("<%=label3.ClientId%>").value = checkedIDs;
```